# Clojure fibonacci series

Tags: clojure

I keep getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: four_cloj.core$my_fib`

```
(defn my-fib []                                                                                                                                                                 
    (let [a 0 b 1]                                                                                                                                                                 
      (lazy-seq (cons a (my-fib b (+ a b))))))
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You define `my-fib` as taking no arguments, but you recursively call it with 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **current** issue is that you are recursively calling `my-fib` with two arguments.

```
(my-fib b (+ a b))
```

But, the function argument list for `my-fib` contains no arguments

```
(defn my-fib []
```